# jquery drop down validation submit

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I am trying to make this drop down menu validation work properly and im hoping that someone can get me to the finish line. At this point the validation works on all the text fields, including the email and phone, as well as the dropdowns. My problem is if I send the form the first time and receive errors it redirects back stating the errors. Now if the user would select all the fields properly and try to resubmit, the submit button does not send. Please for my personal health and sanity someone help me.

Here is the link to the file on my server:
http://amckeedesignportfolio.com/eLearningModule/newForm.php

Here is the code:

```
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>NJR Medical No-Bite V Survey</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
                debug: true,
                success: "valid"
            });;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // validate signup form on keyup and submit
                $("#contactForm").validate({
                    rules: {
                        fName: "required",
                        lName: "required",
                        telephone: "required",
                        email: {
                            required: true,
                            email: true
                        },
                        telephone: {
                            required: true,
                            phoneUS: true
                        },
                        position: "required",
                        hospital: "required",
                        hospitalCity: "required",
                        hospitalState: "required",
                        area: "required",
                        experience: "required",
                        question1: "required",
                        question2: "required",
                        question3: "required",
                        question4: "required",
                        question5: "required",
                        question6: "required",
                        question7: "required",
                        question8: "required",
                        question9: "required",
                        question10: "required",
                        question11: "required",
                    },
                    messages: {
                        fName: "Please enter your firstname.",
                        lName: "Please enter your lastname.",
                        telephone: "Please enter a valid telephone number.",
                        email: "Please specify a valid email address.",
                        position: "Please enter your current position.",
                        hospitalCity: "Please enter your current hospital.",
                        area: "Please enter the current floor or area you work.",
                    }
                });
                /* state validation*/
                $validator.addMethod("required", function (value, element) {
                    return this.optional(element) || (value.indexOf("") == -1);
                }, "Please select a option.");
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="ribbonForm">
                <img src="images/logoLarge.png" alt="NJR Medical Logo" height="60" width="280"
                />
                <h1>Contact Form</h1>
                <h2 class="please">Please take a few minutes to fill out the contact info and short survey
                    so that you can proceed with entering the NJR Medical No-Bite V eLearning
                    Module. All of the questions and contact info must be completed before
                    proceeding to the module.</h2>
                <form name="request" action="newSurveyProcess.php"
                method="POST" id="contactForm" onSubmit="valid_check();">
                    <h2>First Name :
                        <span style="padding-left:25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="textbox_holder">
                        <input name="fName" type="text" class="box" />
                    </div>
                    <h2>Last Name :
                        <span style="padding-left:25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="textbox_holder">
                        <input name="lName" type="text" class="box" />
                    </div>
                    <h2>Contact Number :
                        <span style="padding-left:25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="textbox_holder">
                        <input name="telephone" type="text" class="box" />
                    </div>
                    <h2>Email Address :
                        <span style="padding-left:37px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="textbox_holder">
                        <input name="email" type="text" class="box" />
                    </div>
                    <h2>Position :
                        <span style="padding-left:25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="textbox_holder">
                        <input name="position" type="text" class="box" />
                    </div>
                    <h2>Hospital :
                        <span style="padding-left:25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="textbox_holder">
                        <input name="hospital" type="text" class="box" />
                    </div>
                    <h2>Hospital City :
                        <span style="padding-left:25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="textbox_holder">
                        <input name="hospitalCity" type="text" class="box" />
                    </div>
                    <h2>Hospital State :
                        <span style="padding-left:25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <select name="hospitalState" class="required">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">state</option>
                        <option value="AK">AK</option>
                        <option value="AL">AL</option>
                        <option value="AR">AR</option>
                        <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
                        <option value="CA">CA</option>
                        <option value="CO">CO</option>
                        <option value="CT">CT</option>
                        <option value="DC">DC</option>
                        <option value="DE">DE</option>
                        <option value="FL">FL</option>
                        <option value="GA">GA</option>
                        <option value="HI">HI</option>
                        <option value="IA">IA</option>
                        <option value="ID">ID</option>
                        <option value="IL">IL</option>
                        <option value="IN">IN</option>
                        <option value="KS">KS</option>
                        <option value="KY">KY</option>
                        <option value="LA">LA</option>
                        <option value="MA">MA</option>
                        <option value="MD">MD</option>
                        <option value="ME">ME</option>
                        <option value="MI">MI</option>
                        <option value="MN">MN</option>
                        <option value="MO">MO</option>
                        <option value="MS">MS</option>
                        <option value="MT">MT</option>
                        <option value="NC">NC</option>
                        <option value="ND">ND</option>
                        <option value="NE">NE</option>
                        <option value="NH">NH</option>
                        <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
                        <option value="NM">NM</option>
                        <option value="NV">NV</option>
                        <option value="NY">NY</option>
                        <option value="OH">OH</option>
                        <option value="OK">OK</option>
                        <option value="OR">OR</option>
                        <option value="PA">PA</option>
                        <option value="RI">RI</option>
                        <option value="SC">SC</option>
                        <option value="SD">SD</option>
                        <option value="TN">TN</option>
                        <option value="TX">TX</option>
                        <option value="UT">UT</option>
                        <option value="VA">VA</option>
                        <option value="VT">VT</option>
                        <option value="WA">WA</option>
                        <option value="WI">WI</option>
                        <option value="WV">WV</option>
                        <option value="WY">WY</option>
                    </select>
                    <h2>Area / Floor that you work :
                        <span style="padding-left:25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="textbox_holder">
                        <input name="area" type="text" class="box" />
                    </div>
                    <h2>I have worked in an ICU for:
                        <span style="padding-left:25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <select name="experience" class="required">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">select year range</option>
                        <option value="2">2 yrs</option>
                        <option value="2-4">2-4yrs</option>
                        <option value="5-10">5-10yrs</option>
                        <option value="11-20">11-20yrs</option>
                        <option value="+20yrs">more than 20yrs</option>
                    </select>
                    <h2>Comments :
                        <span style="padding-left:25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <div class="textbox_holder">
                        <textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="60"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Survey Questions</h1>
                    <h2>Please be aware that you must select an answer to every question or your
                        form will not process and allow you to proceed. You must be allowed to
                        proceed for "The No- Bite V eLearning Module" to begin.
                        <span style="padding-left:
                                        25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <h2>1. How often do you have a patient who resists oral care?
                        <span style="padding-left:
                                        25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <br/>
                    <select name="question1" class="required">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">--select--</option>
                        <option value="Never">Never</option>
                        <option value="Rarely">Rarely</option>
                        <option value="Sometimes">Sometimes</option>
                        <option value="Always">Always</option>
                    </select>
                    <h2>2. How often do you have a patient bite on oral swabs with oral care?
                        <span
                        style=" 
                                        padding-left:25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <select name="question2" class="required">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">--select--</option>
                        <option value="Never">Never</option>
                        <option value="Rarely">Rarely</option>
                        <option value="Sometimes">Sometimes</option>
                        <option value="Always">Always</option>
                    </select>
                    <h2>3. Have you ever had a patient break or damage a green swab from biting
                        it?
                        <span style="padding-left:25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <select name="question3" class="required">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">--select--</option>
                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                    </select>
                    <h2>4. How often do you have a patient bite on a Yankauer suction with oral
                        care?
                        <span style="padding-left:25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <select name="question4" class="required">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">--select--</option>
                        <option value="Never">Never</option>
                        <option value="Rarely">Rarely</option>
                        <option value="Sometimes">Sometimes</option>
                        <option value="Always">Always</option>
                    </select>
                    <h2>5. Have you ever had a patient break or damage a Yankauer suction from
                        biting it?
                        <span style="padding-left:25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <select name="question5" class="required">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">--select--</option>
                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                    </select>
                    <h2>6. Have you ever been biten during mouth care.?
                        <span style="padding-left:
                                                25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <select name="question6" class="required">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">--select--</option>
                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                    </select>
                    <h2>7. Do you think patients who bite down and resist oral care tend to receive
                        inadequate oral hygiene?
                        <span style="padding-
    left:25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <select name="question7" class="required">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">--select--</option>
                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                    </select>
                    <h2>8. How often do you have a Naso-Tracheal Suction Catherer coil in the
                        back of a patient's mouth upon insertion?
                        <span style="padding-left:25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <select name="question8" class="required">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">--select--</option>
                        <option value="Never">Never</option>
                        <option value="Rarely">Rarely</option>
                        <option value="Sometimes">Sometimes</option>
                        <option value="Always">Always</option>
                    </select>
                    <h2>9. Do you think that patients who have a Naso- Tracheal Suction Catheter
                        coil in the back of a patient's mouth receive inadequate Naso-Tracheal
                        Suctioning?
                        <span style="
                                                padding-left:25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <select name="question9" class="required">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">--select--</option>
                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                    </select>
                    <h2>10. How often do you have a patient bite an Oral-Pharnygeal Suction Catheter?
                        <span
                        style="padding-left:25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <select name="question10" class="required">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">--select--</option>
                        <option value="Never">Never</option>
                        <option value="Rarely">Rarely</option>
                        <option value="Sometimes">Sometimes</option>
                        <option value="Always">Always</option>
                    </select>
                    <h2>11. Have you ever had a patient damage an Oral- Pharnygeal Suction Catheter
                        from biting it?
                        <span style="padding-
    left:25px;"></span>
                    </h2>
                    <select name="question11" class="required">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">--select--</option>
                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                    </select>
                    <h3>
                        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
                    </h3>
                </form>
                <!--closes form-->
            </div>
            <!--closes ribbonForm -->
        </div>
        <!--closes wrapper-->
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: im starting to wonder if there is a reason why i am getting so many views and no responses?

Comment: The above link, is it working?

Comment: Similarly its better to give another name instead of "required" for the custom rule given in the addMethod.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please remove the following section

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
                debug: true,
                success: "valid"
            });;
```

Now its working.. Please check the link http://jsfiddle.net/R5egy/3/

Comment: you are awesome. thank you. I am currently a student and have only been developing for a little under two years so this site is a great help. It is great to have people out there ,like yourself, that are willing to contribute to assisting in the learning process. I am a designer by heart but developing is a passion of mine. If you ever need assistance in designing, I would be more than happy to assist. pghmediaking@hotmail.com. Thank You.

Comment: @AnthonyMcKee : Thank you..:) Please mark this as answer if it helps you, so that other people can use this..